# A solution for k-CNF in a linear time to the number of clauses, will it be a solution? or it should be linear to the number of different variables

Tags: algorithm, logic, np, sat, cnf

I have a solution that has a linear time complexity to the number of clauses in the CNF formula, which is O(c^2 X n), such that n is the number of different variables in the CNF formula, will this solution be considered as a linear solution to K-CNF or not? Since the number of clauses may be c = 2^n What is the real variable that the algorithm should have it linear in order to solve K-CNF? Can it be C? or it should be n? or what?

I am not understanding the CNF complexity problem correctly

Answer (score 0):

In complexity theory, the runtime of an algorithm is typically measured as a function of the length of the input in bits. So, for example, if your algorithm’s runtime is linear in the number of clauses, since the number of clauses is a linear function of the input size, then your algorithm would be a linear-time solution to k-SAT.

A linear-time algorithm for k-SAT would be a major breakthrough in theoretical CS. Have you tested it extensively? There are (used to be?) yearly competitions for SAT solvers to see just how well they’d perform on huge inputs. You might want to download some test cases from there if you haven’t already done so to validate your algorithm on difficult cases assembled over the last fifty or so years.

Comment: Thank you so much for this clarification, one last question, why do they try to solve CNF according to n (the number of different literals) and at the same time, n is not the real size of the problem, since the real problem size should be according to C the number of clauses, that is why I am confused on why to care about n, not about the real size of the CNF problem?
And I think the number of clauses will not be 2^n since there will be a lot of repetitions in the clauses.
I would love to understand exactly what do mean by a solution for CNF?
Thank you so much for your help and information!

Comment: In practice, it's usually easier to reason about the runtime of an algorithm in terms of a parameter like "how many variables are there?" than a parameter like "how many bits does it take to write out the input?" Most algorithms these days work by manipulating variable assignments, so this is fine.

To your latter point - I think I misinterpreted your question as saying "I have a solution for k-SAT that runs in linear time." If that's not the case, feel free to disregard that comment. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! Really Appreciate :)